# Measure a length of tuples or string

Tags: python, string

I have following string and I want to convert it to array/list so I can measure its length.

```
a="abc,cde,ert,ert,eee"
b="a", "b", "c"
```

The expected length for `a` should be `1` and the expected length for `b` should be `3`.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a string, `b` is a tuple. You can try something like this:

```
def length_of_str_or_tuple(obj):
    if(isinstance(obj,basestring)):
        return 1
    return len(obj)
```

Although what you're doing is really weird and you should probably rethink your approach.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I am just trying to see if there is a way to measure a length here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
>>> a="abc,cde,ert,ert,eee"
>>> b="a", "b", "c"
>>> 1 if isinstance(a, str) else len(a)
1
>>> 1 if isinstance(b, str) else len(b)
3
>>>
```

In the above code, the [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator?lq=1) uses [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to test whether or not `item` is a string object.  It returns `1` if so and `len(item)` if not.

Note that in Python 2.x, you should use `isinstance(item, basestring)` in order to handle both `unicode` and `str` objects.

Comment: is there a way to measure length without using a function since I already have this strings stored inside function.

Comment: Sure, see my edit.  I originally put the code in a function just for convenience.

Comment: `>>> a="abc,cde,ert,ert,eee"
>>> 2 if isinstance(a, str) else len(a)
2`
I believe, I am still not seeing correct solution to measure length for string. For tuple, I can do that with str.split(',').

Comment: Why did you replace `1` with `2`?  You should keep that as is and only change the name of the variable.  The code `1 if isinstance(a, str) else len(a)` is telling Python to return `1` if `a` is a string or `len(a)` if not.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crude way to do this: check which is a string and which a tuple:

```
x ={}

for item in (a,b):
    try:
        item.find('')
        x[item] = 1
    except:
        x[item] = len(item)
```

Since a `tuple` object doesn't have an attribute `find`, it will raise an exception.

Answer (score -3):

To measure the length of the string:

```
len(a.split())
```

for the tuple:

```
len(list(b))
```

combine the previous answers to test for tuple or list and you would get what you want, or use:

```
if type(x) is tuple:    
    len(list(x))    
else:    
    a = x.split("\"")    
    len(a)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by splitting the string on double quotes?  You realize that the quotes used to write a string literal aren't actually in the string, right?

Comment: Explanation:    So, if you try to split string, and strings are immutable, what is returned is a list of the form: ['abc,cde,ert,ert,eee'], using the len() method you get the length of the list.

Comment: string:

"4529,4798,12902788,12020850,12905379,12197558,12904395,"

doing string.split("\")

['', '4529,4798,12902788,12020850,12905379,12197558,12904395,', '']

len(string.split("\""))

3

in my case its counting ' " ' as an element.

Comment: This is the result that you describe above from  a shell:                   >>> a = "4529,4798,12902788,12020850,12905379,12197558,12904395,"
>>> a
'4529,4798,12902788,12020850,12905379,12197558,12904395,'
>>> len(a.split("\""))
1
>>>                                                                             Make sure the dividing character is a "quote". So you have to express it with the escape character "\"".

Comment: @Unihedron It works because his test string doesn't contain a double quote in it. Throw one in and it breaks: http://ideone.com/Iqx022

Comment: You are both right aobut my original answer breaking if there is a literal quote.  However, if there is no splitting character, then it should be ok.  I Just edited the answer.